# Not show anything from setText() or other showing method in pyqt4 inside of threading class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qthread

I write a simple socket app with pyqt4 and threading in python3.3, but i have problem with running Qt classes command like show a message in label or anything, only python code works properly.

Not show anything to S_label in my gui,

I use 2 ways to show any message on S_label but neither of ways not work,

1. self._ui
2. self.ui

in code :

1. self.ui.S_label.setText("test !")
2. self._ui.S_label.setText("test !")
3. self.ui.S_label.setText("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport))

for both two ways `print` works well:

1. print(self._ui)
2. print(self.ui)

`print` output :

-`<imigui.Ui_MainWindow object at 0x7fe0746cac10>`

-`<imigui.Ui_MainWindow object at 0x7fe0746d5d90>`

What I'm doing wrong?

my code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from imigui import Ui_MainWindow

class imiserv(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.setMaxLength(5)
        self.ui.Sconnect_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.serv)

    def serv(self):
        self.sersock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sersock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.host= str(self.ui.Sip_lineEdit.text())
        self.port= int(self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.text())
        MY_LOCK = threading.Lock()
        class CountT(threading.Thread, imiserv):
            def __init__(self, ui, ser):
                super().__init__()
                imiserv.__init__(self)
                self._sersock= ser

                self._ui= ui
                print(self._ui)
                print(self.ui)
                self.ui.S_label.setText("test !")
                self._ui.S_label.setText("test !")

            def run(self):
                MY_LOCK.acquire()
                while True:
                    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._sersock.accept()
                    self.cstr= cliconn.recv(1024)

                    self.ui.S_label.setText("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport))
                    cliconn.close()

                    print(self.cstr)
                MY_LOCK.release()

        try :
            self.sersock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.sersock.listen(5)
            a= CountT(self.ui, self.sersock)
            a.daemon= True # for exit from thread when close gui
            a.start()
        except socket.error as err:
            self.ui.S_label.setText(err)
```

---

**Edit(new problem)** :

I have a new problem with your way:i added a qtextedit to my gui and when i want to settext to it in my code `Segmentation fault` happened and app crashed ,

error :

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x15c4460), parent's thread is QThread(0xfeb570), current thread is QThread(0x15d3900)
Segmentation fault
```

My Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from imigui import Ui_MainWindow

class imiserv(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.setMaxLength(5)
        self.ui.Sconnect_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.serv)

    def serv(self):
        self.sersock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sersock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.host= str(self.ui.Sip_lineEdit.text())
        self.port= int(self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.text())

        MY_LOCK = threading.Lock()
        class CountT(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self, label, ser, qtext):
                super().__init__()
                self._sersock= ser

                self._uilabel= label
                self._uiClog= qtext


            def run(self):
                MY_LOCK.acquire()
                while True:
                    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._sersock.accept()
                    self.cstr= cliconn.recv(1024)

                    self._uilabel.setText("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport))
                    cliconn.close()

                    print(self.cstr)
                    self._uilabel.setText(self.cstr) # it's ok!
                    self._uiClog.setText(msg) # Segmentation fault

                MY_LOCK.release()


        try :
            self.sersock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.sersock.listen(5)
            a= CountT(label= self.ui.S_label, ser= self.sersock, qtext= self.ui.Clog_textEdit)
            a.daemon= True # for exit from thread when close gui
            a.start()
            self.ui.S_label.setText("Connected !")
        except socket.error as err:
            self.ui.S_label.setText(err) # it's ok !
    self.ui.self.ui.Clog_textEdit.setText(err) # it's ok !
```

Why ?

---

**Edit(new problem2)** :

this is my code :

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from imigui import Ui_MainWindow

class imiserv(QtGui.QMainWindow):

```
send_msg = pyqtSignal('QString', 'QString')

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.setMaxLength(5)
    self.ui.Sconnect_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.serv)

    self.send_msg.connect(self.write_msg)

def write_msg(self, lbl_msg= None, txt_msg= None):
    if lbl_msg:
        self.ui.C_label.setText(lbl_msg)
    if txt_msg:
        self.ui.Clog_textEdit.setText(txt_msg)

def serv(self):
    MY_LOCK = threading.Lock()
    class CountT(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self._parent= parent

        def run(self):
            MY_LOCK.acquire()
            self._parent.send_msg.emit("Waiting connections","")
            while True:
                cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
                clirecmsg= str(cliconn.recv(1024)
                self._parent.send_msg.emit("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport), "{0}:{1}".format(addr, remoport)
                cliconn.close()

            MY_LOCK.release()

    try :
        self.clis= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.clis.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        clierhost= str(self.ui.Sip_lineEdit.text())
        clierport= int(self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.text())
        self.clis.bind((clierhost, clierport))
        self.clis.listen(5)
        a= CountT(self)
        a.daemon= True
        a.start()
    except socket.error as err:
        err= str(err)
        print(err)
```

and this is error that happened decussate, i should press button twice for get event for first time error showed in linux and nothing in windows and for second press event is happened,(this error show only in linux os.)

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "imiclilap.py", line 34, in run
    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "imiclilap.py", line 34, in run
    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me (Python 2.6 here). I removed the inheritance of `CountT` with `imiserv` and replaced the ui object by <del>the QLabel `S_label`</del> the `imiserv` instance instead. A `pyqtsignal` allows the thread CounT to write text to the QLabel and the QTextEdit:

```
import socket
import threading

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from imigui import Ui_MainWindow

class imiserv(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    send_msg = pyqtSignal('QString', 'QString')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.setMaxLength(5)
        self.ui.Sconnect_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.serv)

        self.send_msg.connect(self.my_slot)

    def write_msg(self, lbl_msg, txt_msg):
        self.ui.S_label.setText(lbl_msg)
        self.ui.Clog_textEdit.setText(txt_msg)

    def serv(self):
        self.sersock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sersock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.host= str(self.ui.Sip_lineEdit.text())
        self.port= int(self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.text())
        MY_LOCK = threading.Lock()
        class CountT(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self._parent= parent

            def run(self):
                MY_LOCK.acquire()
                self._parent.send_msg.emit("Waiting connections","")
                while True:
                    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self.__parent.sersock.accept()
                    self.cstr= cliconn.recv(1024)
                    self._parent.send_msg.emit("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport), self.cstr)
                    cliconn.close()

                MY_LOCK.release()

        try :
            self.sersock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.sersock.listen(5)
            a= CountT(self)
            a.daemon= True # for exit from thread when close gui
            a.start()
        except socket.error as err:
            self.ui.S_label.setText(err.strerror.decode("utf-8"))
            self.ui.Clog_textEdit.setText(err.strerror.decode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  s = imiserv()
  s.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Completely Works !!! Thanks , but can u say to me why this problem happened ?? why inheritance not work ?what is wrong in that way ?

Comment: The inheritance had no sense, but it was not the problem I think. Giving the lineedit widget as argument solved the problem.

Comment: I have a new problem with your way:i added a qtextedit to my gui and when i want to settext to it in my code 'Segmentation fault' happened: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x15c4460), parent's thread is QThread(0xfeb570), current thread is QThread(0x15d3900)
Segmentation fault   , why ?

Comment: Can you either edit your question with your new code or create another question ? It's gonna be difficult to analyze the problem inside the comment section.

Comment: Writing text into the QTextEdit lead to an exception because it was done in another thread. I don't know why this is was not a problem for the QLabel. I edited my answer: a signal was added to the imserv class. This signal is connected to a slot designed to write text in the qlabel and the qtextedit. The signal is emitted by the thread when necessary. Note that the CounT class has now only 1 argument to its constructor: an instance of imiserv. The CounT instance has now access to the socket as well as the pyqtsignal.

Comment: Works !! Thank you very much ! with parent in CountT constructor can access to imi class elements or what?where can i read about that more ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you have access to all members of the imiserv instance using `self._parent`. It's just standard Python: you give to a class an instance of another class, which allows you to use its methods and have access to its attributes. In your case; this allows to avoid any Qt-related call directly from within the thread.

Comment: i tested my client app in windowz and that was ok without any error but in linux with python3.3 this error happened and just showed without exit from app,Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "imiclilap.py", line 55, in run
    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: `sersock` is now called `clis` ?

Comment: no! in my original code some variable name is different with example code in here,  `self._parent.sersock.accept()` is right.

Comment: So you should update your code above tor reflect your current code

Comment: added , thanks . this problem show only in linux os and in windwz not show any things.

Comment: @alireza.m: I won't be able to look at your problem for the next month (holidays).